# Why are these extra 's's appearing on my concatenated list?

Tags: python, loops, concatenation

I am trying to make a program that generates a deck of 52 non-repeating cards. Each card has a value between 2 and 13 and is then assigned a suit. I managed to get some results, but it doesn't quite work. I just want it to look like [2s, 3s, 4s, ... 13s, 2c, 3c, ....] etc until it exhausts all four suits.

```
s = 0
value = list(range(2, 14))
sDeck = []
cDeck = []
hDeck = []
dDeck = []

while s <= 3:
    if s == 0:
        sDeck = [x + 's' for x in str(value)]
    elif s == 1:
         cDeck = [x + 'c' for x in str(value)]
    elif s == 2:
        hDeck = [x + 'h' for x in str(value)]
    elif s == 3:
        dDeck = [x + 'd' for x in str(value)]
    s += 1
Deck = sDeck + cDeck + hDeck + dDeck
```

The results I am getting are just a mess. I imagine I have a very fundamental piece of understanding missing when it comes to writing loops.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is hidden here:

```
cDeck = [x + 'c' for x in str(value)]
```

`value` is a list which look like

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

when you wrap it with `str()` you get a string yes, but it looks like

```
'[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]'
```

So when you iterate over this string you deffinately will observe a wrong result.
To fix this problem your code should be:

```
sDeck = [str(x) + 's' for x in value]
```

Here you wrap with `str()` each separate value from range.

P.S. you also can use just `value = range(2, 14)` instead of `value = list(range(2, 14))`

Answer (score 0):

`str(value)` doesn't convert each of your list element to a string, use `map(str, value)` instead.

```
s = 0
value = list(range(2, 14))
sDeck = []
cDeck = []
hDeck = []
dDeck = []

while s <= 3:
    if s == 0:
        sDeck = [x + 's' for x in map(str, value)]
    elif s == 1:
         cDeck = [x + 'c' for x in map(str, value)]
    elif s == 2:
        hDeck = [x + 'h' for x in map(str, value)]
    elif s == 3:
        dDeck = [x + 'd' for x in map(str, value)]
    s += 1
Deck = sDeck + cDeck + hDeck + dDeck

print(sDeck)
print(cDeck)
print(hDeck)
print(dDeck)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest two iterators in a list comprehension. So one simple way to get that deck would be:

```py
deck = [ str(card)+suit for suit in 'schd' for card in range(2,14) ]
```

Note that when you have two `for` clauses in a comprehension, the first one is the outer loop; the idea is that it mimics the order of iteration of an explicit loop:

```py
for suit in 'schd':
    for card in range(2, 14):
        deck.append(str(card) + suit)
```

You can also write that with an "f-string":

```py
deck = [ f"{card}{suit}" for suit in 'schd' for card in range(2,14) ]
```